# How to store an array of Float16 in BigQuery?

Tags: serialization, google-bigquery

BQ has no issue converting my python floats to Float64 and storing them directly. It is however inflates size of data and data transfer. I only need this data for occasional usage, read it for the entire table at once and never use it in queries or joins. In other words, I am fine just serializing it and deserializing it later.

Is there a recommended way to store a serialized binary object in BQ, or maybe there is some magic that would allow me to use Float16 as is?